# Check CPU utlization of processes, but it is throwing output as well as with an error

Tags: powershell

Wrote the below script to get highest CPU utlization of 10 processes in decending order. It is giving desired output but with an error. How to suppress this error?

```
Get-Counter -Computername RKCDR1 -Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' |
    Select -ExpandProperty countersamples |
    Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue |
    Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 10 |
    ft -AutoSize
```

Giving below output with error:

```
Get-Counter : The data in one of the performance counter samples is not valid.
View the Status property for each PerformanceCounterSample object to make sure
it contains valid data.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Computername RKCDR1 -Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

InstanceName            CookedValue
------------            -----------
_total             199.988940611584
idle               110.931365495488
verasmart          87.4951615175681
sqlservr             1.562413598528
callmanagerexpress                0
wmiprvse                          0
msdtc                             0
spserver                          0
felt32                            0
java                              0
```

Comment: Have you tried adding  `-ErrorAction Ignore`?

Comment: Tried Below with -ErrorAction . It worked.
Thanks a lot



        Get-Counter -Computername RKCDR1 -Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' -ErrorAction Ignore | Select -ExpandProperty countersamples | Select-Object -Property instancename,  cookedvalue| Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 10| ft -AutoSize